# Laravel pagination vs Datatables performance

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, pagination, datatables

This is general question about site performance.
Lets assume that I'm going to have shop with thousands of products etc...

I want to load list of max 30 products on each page, should I use inbuilt [pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination) of laravel or [datatables](https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable)?

Is there any huge advantage of using pagination over datatables or datatables over pagination?

I have used both, pagination and datatables on laravel and both works fine, but I have no experience with databases that got thousands of products, which my current project is aiming for.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Its more about ajax. If you think datatables without ajax requests its simply same as classic pagination

There is no difference in database operations with those methods

Its all about loading the data after page loaded or before making page. You will use same queries to achieve this. Personally i would use datatables with smooth loading animations for better user experience

Answer (score 0):

Datatables would not normally be the best choice for a shopfront with thousands of items.

The benefit that you get with **Datatables** is that it gives you things such as ordering, searching and pagination for free. This is especially handy on admin backends, where you may need to show tens of thousands of items  (*if not more*)  on your admin backend.

If you are going to be showing products (say on a shop front) you are most likely going to want to have control over all of the styling, images etc.

At this point Datatables starts loosing many of its benefits.

You might want to look at using custom AJAX requests with some Javascript templating to give you full control over how your products will be rendered.